# Добавление текста из uitextfield в uitableview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift4, uitextfield

Есть текстфилд отдельно от таблицы (расположен не в ячейке таблицы), но на этом же контроллере. Необходимо, чтобы при вводе слова, уже с первой буквы, эта буква и последующие набираемые автоматически сразу отображались в лэйбле расположенном в ячейке таблицы, в процессе написания. А так же отображались все доступные слова из массива с этими же буквами (те добиться того, чтобы таблица предлагала выбор слов из массива с таким порядком букв как введеные. Но в таблице отображаться должно вводимое слово и примеры для выбора только после начала ввода слова. С первой задачей справился, код в вопросе подправил, а с фильтром слов для выбора пока не получается. заранее спасибо

```
@IBOutlet weak var checkTextField: UITextField!
var tableData = ["арбуз", "баклажан", "вино", "груша", "жимолость", "зерно", "иголка", "кружка", "лампа", "машина"]
var filterThing = [""]

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textFieldText = checkTextField.text

    let filtered = tableData.filter {$0.lowerCased().contains(textFieldText.lowerCased())}//НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО РЕАЛИЗУЮ ФИЛЬТР
    filterThing.append(contentsOf: filtered)

    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filterThing.count + 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailCell") as! DetailCell

    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 0 && (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 0 {
        cell.thingNameLabel?.text = textFieldText
    } else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 0 && (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row > 0 {
        cell.thingNameLabel?.text = filterThing[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: textFieldDidChange - на какое событие это у Вас срабатывает? filterThing.append(contentsOf: filtered) - а предварительно очищать? Или сразу присваивать фильтрованный массив. Зачем (indexPath as NSIndexPath)?

Comment: textFieldDidChange срабатывает когда в uitextfield начинаю вводить символы. (indexPath as NSIndexPath) для того чтобы отделить первую ячейку от последующих, тк в первой ячейке отображается конкретно тот текст, который ввожу, а в последующих одновременно отображаются слова из массива отфильтрованные по подобию уже введеных символов. Например в массиве из множества слов есть арбуз, арахис, айва. И при введенных в текстфилде "ар", в первой ячейке отображается ар, а в последующих двух - арбуз и арахис. Айва не отображается тк второй символ у этого слова не Р, а Й

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для поиска строк с соответствующими символами из строки для поиска оптимально использовать регулярные выражения. Для Вашего случая пример:

```
let tableData = ["ананас", "яблоком", "локомотив", "ломик"]
let stringToFind = "лом"
// Подготавливаем для нужных условий
let regexPattern = stringToFind.map{ String($0) }.joined(separator: ".*")
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexPattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
    // Ищем
    let filteredData = tableData.filter {
        regex.firstMatch(in: $0, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: $0.count)) != nil
    }
    print(filteredData)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

будет найдено

> ["яблоком", "локомотив", "ломик"]

Comment: у меня почему-то filteredData выдает пустым массивом. Скрин добавил в вопрос. Хотя contentOfList в моем скрине массив var contentOfList = ["арбуз", "арахис", "баклажан", "вино", "груша"], а textFieldText - это текст из символов введеных в текстфилд. Иеще вопросик,  а искать слова с расположением букв в таком же порядке как и введеные символы можно, или по будут искаться слова с символами в любом порядке? Те в вашем примере должно было отобразиться только ЛОМИК

Comment: @ArturSkachkov пустые, потому что у Вас `stringToFind` optional. В моем примере слова ищутся по соответствующим символам в соответствующем порядке, но не учитывая что между ними. Т.е. в общем случае слово выглядит для поиска так: `**ло**м`, `ло**м****`, `*******`.